# Handling locales for formal and informal language in Java

Tags: java, locale

In Java we have java.util.Locale for language/region handling. For my county that would be "nl_BE" (Dutch language in Belgian region). The locale is usually deeply embedded in the way a website is translated.

However, for my current webapp, I want to have both support for formal and informal language on the site. The informal language would be for consumers and the formal language would be for business customers.

Now, I was wondering how to best deal with this situation.

One idea I had would be to create a new kind of locale: "nl_BE_formal" and "nl_BE_informal", but that is quite unorthodox.

Do you have any experience with this kind of situation? How would you handle text translations for the same language and region, but with a different tone of voice?

PS: To be more specific, my project uses Spring MVC and I have created my own translation logic. Strings are stored in HashMaps per locale and per language with a fallback system. To solve my problem, I could create an extra level for formal/informal, but I wanted to ask this question in a general way to learn how others handle this kind of problem in Java apps using Locale or other techniques. So, I'm not really looking for an answer to my source code problem, but more general advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seem [private locale extensions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/locale/extensions.html)?

By the way. Do you really need hashmaps for strings? The resource files mechanism seems good enough. I may be wrong but it seems as a case of reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Yes, I am reinventing the wheel a bit, but it's for my own convenience, and a bit off-topic here :)

Comment: This looks like a good solution, but I will keep this open for a little while to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: No more answers were coming, so I will accept this. Thank you very much!